# incomplete implementation of interfaces in clojure

Tags: interface, clojure, deftype

Clojure allows `deftype`s that implement an interface incompletely, such as

```
(deftype Foo [x] clojure.lang.ISeq (next [this] x))
```

(`Foo` does not implement `seq`).  Coming from the Pythonic land of duck-typing, or, at best (or worst, depending on your POV), ABCs, I have trouble understanding why such incomplete are allowed implementations, as I thought the point of interfaces was to guarantee the presence of a set of methods (as it is right now, it seems that to use other people's `deftype`s safely I'd have to wrap each "method" call in a `try...catch`).

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the intersections between Clojure the dynamic language philosophy and Java the static language philosophy. and it does show a point of confusion between the two, I agree. The rationale was to **allow clojure programs to use Java libraries** without any undue pain, and many libraries require you to **pass an instance of some class that implements a method** by way of getting around Java's lack of first class functions. From that perspective, the trade off makes sense, although from the other perspectives it doesn't quite fit the Java Philosophy.

Answer (score 1):

Requiring complete implementation defeats interactive programming. If someone provides you a type that doesn't fully implement ISeq, they have given you a broken type. That said, a Clojure linter / analyzer that checks your source for implementation oversights sounds pretty useful.

Comment: Sure, requiring a complete implementation makes interactive programming harder but how cac you claim you implement ISeq when you actually don't?  I mean, if you are allowed not to fully implement an interface then I may as well claim that my piece of code implements all existing interfaces (it just happens to raise AbstractMethodError every so often).

Comment: @atony, I've been writing Clojure for 4 years. This isn't a problem in practice.

Comment: I guess this means protocols should really be thought as a form of metadata, and that only protocol functions are "real"?